# Why replace method works in Yandex Contest, but replaceAll don't (javascript, nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had a task, where i used `replaceAll` regex method and could not pass many tests in Yandex Contest testing system, but locally everything seems to work properly. I decided to use `replace` with `g` modifier instead, and all tests passed. I wonder what was the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you didn't include the `g` modifier when using `relaceAll`?

As stated in the documentation of [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#:%7E:text=A%20RegExp%20without%20the%20global%20(%22g%22)%20flag%20will%20throw%20a%20TypeError%3A%20%22replaceAll%20must%20be%20called%20with%20a%20global%20RegExp%22.)

> A RegExp without the global ("g") flag will throw a TypeError:
> "replaceAll must be called with a global RegExp".

Comment: both variants did not work